JavaFX+mybatis+sqlite Could not find resource mapper/UserMapper.xml
When I create a sample-demo use JavaFX+mybatis+sqlite
Could not find resource mapper/UserMapper.xml when I create the folder 'mapper' in 'src/main/resources/',

when I debug in Resources.getResourceAsStream(),I found the systemClassLoader's path is not my resources path in ClassLoaderWrapper.systemClassLoader
Here is the error message
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.qcrrm.mybatissqlitedemo/com.qcrrm.mybatissqlitedemo.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick(HelloController.java:19)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error building SqlSession.
### The error may exist in mapper/UserMapper.xml
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mapper/UserMapper.xml
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:82)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:66)
    at com.qcrrm.mybatissqlitedemo/com.qcrrm.mybatissqlitedemo.util.MybatisUtil.<clinit>(MybatisUtil.java:24)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mapper/UserMapper.xml
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:122)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parse(XMLConfigBuilder.java:99)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:80)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mapper/UserMapper.xml
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:114)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:100)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.mapperElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:378)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:120)
    ... 63 more

Process finished with exit code 0

And It works when I create only File UserMapper.xml in 'src/main/resources/'
github-pro

Please try the latest version of MyBatis (3.5.16 as of this writing).

I try the latest version(2.5.16) but also Could not find resource。

When I try to change the UserMapper.xml to real path,it's Ok.
<mapper url="file:\\E:\pro\java\fx\mybatis-sqlite-demo\src\main\resources\mapper\UserMapper.xml"/>

this is my pro in github -> github-pro

There needs to be a line opens mapper to org.mybatis in module-info.java.

If MyBatis uses a ClassLoader to access the resource then use opens mapper; instead (i.e., use an unqualified opens instead of a qualified one).

With enough reputation (15) you can answer your own question to note the exact steps you took that resolved the problem.

The error you're getting is:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mapper/UserMapper.xml
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:114)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:100)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.mapperElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:378)
    at org.mybatis@3.5.11/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:120)
    ... 63 more

Note: You may want to upgrade to the latest version of MyBatis, which as of this answer is 3.5.16.
From your screenshot, that resource definitely exists. But your code is modular and the UserMapper.xml resource is in a directory named mapper. And since that is a valid package name that all means the resource is encapsulated. If you want code outside your module to be able to access that resource via the standard resource lookup API, then you need to opens that package.
In your case it will have to be an unqualified opens. Why? Because MyBatis tries to find the resource via ClassLoader objects. From ClassLoader::getResourceAsStream:

Resources in named modules are subject to the encapsulation rules specified by Module.getResourceAsStream. Additionally, and except for the special case where the resource has a name ending with ".class", this method will only find resources in packages of named modules when the package is opened unconditionally.

In short, you need to add an:
opens mapper;

Directive to your module-info.java file.

As an aside, MyBatis does not appear to be modular yet. That means org.mybatis is an automatic module. Having a direct dependency on an automatic module negates many of the benefits of using modules. For instance, the jlink tool cannot work with automatic modules. You may want to consider making your code non-modular (i.e., removing your module-info.java file completely). Though since you're using JavaFX, you should make sure at least JavaFX keeps being resolved as named modules if possible (see https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ for examples of that).
